# Host Identification has changed for no obvious reason

Tags: networking, server, ssh

This is the error I'm getting when I tried login in to my server

```
 ssh abayomi@143.110.229.222
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:nLdtZYZ3MPLkpSPFJWFEO0bn8/mlG3Oe0NtEYdKbcNU.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /home/abayomi/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ECDSA key in /home/abayomi/.ssh/known_hosts:3
  remove with:
  ssh-keygen -f "/home/abayomi/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "143.110.229.222"
ECDSA host key for 143.110.229.222 has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

OK I just successfully removed the previous hostname, I then tried to do this
`ssh 143.198.104.166`
I'm now getting this error
`abayomi@143.198.104.166: Permission denied (publickey).`
my user no longer has access to login to the server.

Comment: Just copy and execute this line `ssh-keygen -f "/home/abayomi/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "143.110.229.222"` that should solve the problem, forthemore it is recommended to remove private details such as username and ip.

Comment: how then would i add my new host name

Comment: The command should solve the problem, exexute the command frome your pc terminal and reconnect with the normal `ssh` command, the reconnetion via `ssh` will re-add your hostname to the server.

Comment: please check my updated question i was getting an error

Comment: I can login as root but I can't login with my user

Comment: how can I give my user access to login again?

Comment: Note that you are trying to connect different ip, you fixed the hostname issue for 143.110 and the permission error is for 143.198, the error means that you do not have keys to 143.198 server.

Comment: so I'm in the sever as root how can I give my user access again

Comment: Please i don't want to create another user

Answer (score 1):

1. `ssh` Secure Shell - is a program for logging into a remote machine and for executing commands on a remote machine.
2. To connect remote server you have to install "ssh server" Secure Shell Daemon - `sshd`.
3. `sshd` usually listen to port 22 and you can connect the ssh server by using the command `ssh username@hostname`
4. You can change your ssh server configuration by editing the configuration file  `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`
5. **To your specific question:**

   - The known_hosts problem may cause because you're using the same remote computer address as before but the remote computer is responding with a different fingerprint.
   - Therefore as i commented the command `ssh-keygen -f "/home/abayomi/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "143.110.229.222"` will solve the warning message problem.
   - The "permission deniend" error caused because you do not have keys to the specific server.
   - To add more keys to ssh server you have to add your public key to the authorized_keys file which located on `/home/username/.ssh/authorized_keys` or in the root user `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`.
   - To generate new keys you can use the `ssh-keygen` command.